# Code for factoring doesn't work with large numbers?

Tags: python

I have a large 512 bit number n and I need to rewrite n-1 as m*2k
Here is the code I wrote:
    # write (n-1) = m*2^k (where m is odd)

```
k = 0       # number of times we were able to divide by 2
total = (n-1)                                                                     

while total % 2 == 0:                                                             
    total /= 2                                                                    
    k += 1                                                                        

m = int(total)                                                                                     
assert (n-1) == (2**k) * m          # this does not hold true for large values of n for some reason
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for large (515 bit) values of n such as:
    8711599454063889217821738854601954834373650047096243407624954758041578156381215983765719390767527065267731131102484447503200895621045535585981917487924709

For the above value of n, my code found k = 460 and m =2926172291557515

When I evaluate 2926172291557515 * 2**460 in python I get:
    8711599454063889889401923055669626316647070894345982715097720460936366477064539266279767451213791729696559357170292404522606916263895951485640687369584640

Which does not equal n-1. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I assume it's related to having such large numbers (this code works fine for lower numbers that I test it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises because you are using `/=` which is float division. Replace it with `//=`, or integer division, and your code will work.

Answer (score 3):

@Primusa is correct. In Python3.x `/` (or `/=`) returns a `float` value, so loses a lot of precision.

```
>>> n = 8711599454063889217821738854601954834373650047096243407624954758041578156381215983765719390767527065267731131102484447503200895621045535585981917487924709
>>> total = (n-1)
>>> total / 2
4.355799727031945e+153
>>> total // 2
4355799727031944608910869427300977417186825023548121703812477379020789078190607991882859695383763532633865565551242223751600447810522767792990958743962354
```